# Click function won't update information on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my submit button to pull the value from the input box next to it, change the '#' to a '-' and then pass it on so that I can pull information respective to that user and then populate the field in HTML. But the page just refreshes and a '?' gets added to the url.

```
$("#usernameBtn").click(function() {
    var unTouchedID = $("#userid").val();
    var usrID = unTouchedID.replace("#", "-");

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/" + usrID + "/stats",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "", 
        success: function (data) {
        $('#heroStats_elims').html('<h2>'+ data.us.stats.competitive.average_stats.eliminations_avg + '</h2>'); 
    //var avgElims = //data.us.stats.competitive.average_stats.eliminations_avg
        }
    }); });


<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Battle.net Tag" id="userid">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="usernameBtn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Try with `<button type="button" ...>`. This will remove the behavior to submit the page.

Comment: Just a thought: don't you need to use `event.preventDefault()` to keep the form from actually submitting? It seems like all your code is executing, but after your click function runs, the default function for the button _also_ runs, which in this case means submitting the form. If the form has no target, then it will appear as though it is just refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.preventDefault();` as @Andrew mentioned to prevent the default behavior of submitting the page.

```js
$("#usernameBtn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var unTouchedID = $("#userid").val();
  var usrID = unTouchedID.replace("#", "-");

  $.ajax({
      url: "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/" + usrID + "/stats",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: "", 
      success: function (data) {
      $('#heroStats_elims').html('<h2>'+ data.us.stats.competitive.average_stats.eliminations_avg + '</h2>'); 
      //var avgElims = //data.us.stats.competitive.average_stats.eliminations_avg
      }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Battle.net Tag" id="userid">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="usernameBtn">Submit</button>
```